# Increasing Linq to XML Parsing performance

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I have been working in a XML parser using Linq to XML and parsing throught foreach loops.

The program works, but it is slow because I have 2 roots with lots of elements inside, and the elements of those two roots can be related. (The file is not big, it has from 1Mb to 5Mb).

So, to clarify, I have `<Datas>` and `<Symbols>` roots, inside the .xml file. The elements inside `<Symbols>`, are related to the `<Datas>` elements through each of the `<Symbol>` child `<Type>`, as it follows:

```
<Datas>
     <Data>
        <Name>**SymbolType_1**</Name> // (As you can see, <Name> = <Type> of the <Symbol>)
        <Type>DataType1</Type>
            <Subitem>
                <Name>SubitemName1</Name>
                <Type>SubitemType1</Type>
            </Subitem>
            <Subitem>
                <Name>SubitemName1</Name>
                <Type>SubitemType1</Type>
            </Subitem>
     </Data>
     <Data>
        <Name>**SymbolType_2**</Name>
            <Subitem>
                <Name>SubitemName1</Name>
                <Type>SubitemType1</Type>
            </Subitem>
            <Subitem>
                <Name>SubitemName1</Name>
                <Type>SubitemType1</Type>
            </Subitem>
     </Data>
     [...]
</Datas>

<Symbols>
     <Symbol>
         <Name>SymbolName_1</Name>
         <Type>**SymbolType_1**</Type>
     </Symbol>
     <Symbol>
         <Name>SymbolName_1</Name>
         <Type>**SymbolType_1**</Type>
     </Symbol>
     [...]
</Symbols>
```

So, it is possible, also, that some `<Subitem>` `<Type>` is connected to another `<Data>`, creating a structure of 10 elements.

What I do now is use a `foreach` loop getting each `<Symbol>` and apply methods to look each `<Data>`, and its respective `<Subitem>` children.

Since I am starting in C#, I would like to know if would it be a good idea to store all `<Symbol>`, `<Data>` and `<Subitem>` in two or three different `<List>`, parsing through the lists instead of through the file.

Also, would it be smart (and possible) to split the `<Symbols>` in "areas" and use more than one foreach loop simultaneously responsible to parse each of them?

At last, I would like to know if would it be possible to store the position of each `<Data>`, so I do not need to parse since the start of the root `<Datas>`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your usage. If the XML is that small though, I'd just as soon deserialize it (say with the `XmlSerializer`) into an object model once and create some nice Dictionary lookups instead of using Linq-to-XML. EDIT: I don't know if Linq-to-XML has some optimizations in place, but if you're frequently re-querying the data or re-iterating the XML tree, that sounds like it could be a performance hit.

Comment: you can use xpath navigate to special node in you xml document.

Comment: The very fastest way to parse XML is with an XmlTextReader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ChrisSinclair linq-to-xml reads the entire file into memory. Once it is parsed, it exists as an `XNode` object graph.

Comment: Oh also, if you're talking about performance, can you go into a bit more detail about that? For example, simply deserializing 1 to 5 MB of XML data is _pretty fast_. I mean, it might be _slow_ according to some benchmarks relative to other operations, but what are you trying to do with it? Are you trying to read it many hundreds of times per second? A single read into memory should only take a negligible amount of time.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair So, the problem is that (in this file) there are more than 400 `<Symbol>` and more than 500 `<Data>`. Considering that each `<Data>` might have around 5 to 10 `<Subitem>`.

So, for each `<Symbol>`, I can go through `<Data>` a lot of times, because the `<Subitem>` can be related to another `<Data>`, with more `<Subitem>`, and on, and on... So, the point is that I parse throuhg all `<Datas>` everytime I find a `<Symbol>` or `<Subitem>`, and that is making it slow.
I will check the usage of XmlTextReader, but I wouldn`t like to create a whole new program, since this one is already

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a Dictionary to store each item; i.e.

```
var symbols = new Dictionary<string, Symbol>();
var datas = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
```

and then load them at startup; using a list means you'll (potentially) have to go through the entire collection to find the correct item; using a dictionary, you'll be able to access it directly with a key.

Comment: I will check the usage of Dictionaries, since it appear to provide a way to avoid parsing the whole `<Datas>` to find one `<Data>` Element, each time I check a `<Symbol>` or `<Subitem>`. Thanks :)

Comment: You could also try ConcurrentDictionary and then use Parallel.ForEach to process your XML but you'll need a minimum of .Net 4.0 for that.